# JSON Formatting out of Zapier

Tags: json, zapier

Ayo my name is Monte, I'm not super technical and I'm having a problem sending some data back out of zapier. I've run the code through debuggers and it's reading multiple errors but they don't make sense to me when I ask chatgpt it says no syntax/formatting errors so I've kinda exhausted all my non-technical resources. This is my last hope

The error messages from the JSON debugger dont even look like they are there in zapier, The prompts for gpt in zapier arent starting or ending with quotes so its not that.

Comment: Sounds tough. Did you have a question, though?

Comment: It sounds like you're having some trouble sending data out of Zapier, and you're seeing some error messages in the JSON debugger. Could you provide more specific details about the errors you're encountering, including the message and any relevant code snippets?